# c# casting to generic type fails on Guid

Tags: c#

I am trying to change the type of a property of an object and when i use this it doesn't convert `convert.changetype` from string to guid and when i looked up i found out that if the guid is nullable it wont pass so i followed an article that explained that the default method doesn't work with nullables the only thing i can't fix is converting the x value to y entity type knowing x is a string and y is the guid.

**Custom Change Type Class to skip the nullable issue**

```
public static object ChangeType(object value, Type conversionType)
    {
        // Note: This if block was taken from Convert.ChangeType as is, and is needed here since we're
        // checking properties on conversionType below.
        if (conversionType == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("conversionType");
        } // end if

        // If it's not a nullable type, just pass through the parameters to Convert.ChangeType

        if (conversionType.IsGenericType &&
          conversionType.GetGenericTypeDefinition().Equals(typeof(Nullable<>)))
        {
            // It's a nullable type, so instead of calling Convert.ChangeType directly which would throw a
            // InvalidCastException (per http://weblogs.asp.net/pjohnson/archive/2006/02/07/437631.aspx),
            // determine what the underlying type is
            // If it's null, it won't convert to the underlying type, but that's fine since nulls don't really
            // have a type--so just return null
            // Note: We only do this check if we're converting to a nullable type, since doing it outside
            // would diverge from Convert.ChangeType's behavior, which throws an InvalidCastException if
            // value is null and conversionType is a value type.
            if (value == null)
            {
                return null;
            } // end if

            // It's a nullable type, and not null, so that means it can be converted to its underlying type,
            // so overwrite the passed-in conversion type with this underlying type
            NullableConverter nullableConverter = new NullableConverter(conversionType);
            conversionType = nullableConverter.UnderlyingType;
        } // end if

        // Now that we've guaranteed conversionType is something Convert.ChangeType can handle (i.e. not a
        // nullable type), pass the call on to Convert.ChangeType

        return Convert.ChangeType(value, conversionType);
    }
```

**Tried to convert it this way but i couldn't get the T type**

```
(T)TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(T)).ConvertFromInvariantString(text);
(instance.GetType())TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(instance.GetType().).ConvertFromInvariantString(text);
```

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: using convert.changeType(value, type) doesn't work when it's string to guid and nothing i tried worked

Comment: If you really truly did try to code this yourself, then why didn't you include your attempt in the question.  As it stands, your question has no proof that you tried, and therefore will be down voted and closed.  And you did not even ask a question.  Don't just state your problem and imply the question. ASK the question outright.

Comment: alright i will post what i used

Comment: i hope that's enough proof now

Answer (score -2):

If you're trying to convert the string to a GUID, why not pass ou it to the Guid constructor (e.g., {Guid temp = new Guid(stringValue)}? If the string is empty, create an empty Guid.

Comment: the type is generic so it can't be new Guid(string)

Comment: But if it is known that you need to go from the string to the Guid inside the generic, you convert the genetic toa string and create the Guid.